# Matlab, colorbar label

Tags: matlab, plot, label, colorbar

Just wondering, how do you alter code so that the title of a colorbar appears along the length of it instead of across the top of it. My colorbar is vertical and to the right of my contour plot. I can put a lable on top of it but I am unable to put one down the length of it. Also does anyone know how to write superscript in matlab. I'm trying to write U' but when I use "'" the command line closes.
Regards,
Jer

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ylabel` to assign a label to the colorbar. Moreover, in order to print superscripts use `^{Text here}`. If you want subscripts, use `_{Text here}`.

Simple example:

```
clear
clc
close all

contourf(peaks)
hC = colorbar('eastoutside');

LabelText = 'Label with ^{superscript}'; %// Use superscript

ylabel(hC,LabelText,'FontSize',16)
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

If you want it rotated by 180 degrees, you can get the position of the ylabel and modify it a bit, then flipping it by 180 degrees. i.e. add these lines:

```
LabelPos = get(get(hC,'YLabel'),'Position')
set(get(hC,'YLabel'),'Position',[LabelPos(1) + 4 LabelPos(2) LabelPos(3)],'Rotation',-90)
```

You basically get the position of the current ylabel and shift its x position a couple pixels so that it does not overlap with the colorbar.
This gives:

[image]

**EDIT**:
According to your comments, here is how you can format the YTick labels:

```
CellLabel = str2double(cellstr(get(hC,'YTickLabel'))); %// Convert current label to numbers
StringLabel = cell(1,numel(CellLabel));
for k = 1:numel(CellLabel)

    StringLabel{k} = sprintf('%0.3f',CellLabel(k)); %// format into the format you want.
end
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i was trying to do. However, for the label I am trying to write u' but when I write LabelText = 'U ^{'}'; i get the error                                     Error: File: Rstress066D.m Line: 16 Column: 19
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

Comment: Oh then you might want to use this: `ylabel(hC,'U''','FontSize',16)`. I.e. use 2 apostrophes to print a single one

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question. I have data in the order of 1e-3. How can i display values on the colorbar as .003 etc instead of 3 with x10-3 on top of the bar?

Comment: You can use `A = cellstr(get(hC,'YTickLabel'))`to get a cell array of strings, and then play around with `sprintf` to format the output as you want.

Comment: Sorry but how would I use sprintf to alter the notation on the colorbar? Do i write `Yticklabel = sprintf (%0.4f)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to write different code to fix my problem but thanks again! here is the code i used `hd= colorbar;
set(hd, 'YTickLabel', cellstr(num2str(reshape(get(hd, 'YTick'),[],1),'%0.3f')) )`. Sorry I just could not follow the for loop you used.